# How do I show a blank page in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

In Firefox I can type about:blank in the URL and it opens a blank page. I can then open the console in Firebug and test adding elements and so on. How can I do this in Safari? I tried about:blank and it did not load at all though the network said it was loading something (30 seconds and no response). I then tried opening a new tab but Web Console was grayed out and would not allow me to edit the page.

I would like to test JavaScript on a blank page in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can set safari to always open a blank page at first.

```
Safari preferences / General tab

New window opens with: choose Empty Page
```

Comment: @1.21gigawatts happy to help :)